# Why in angular , the changes in scope properties are not reflected back to the view dynamically when we do not assign a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The html is :

```
<body ng-app='myModule' ng-controller='myController'>
  <div class="container">
    <br>

    <input class='form-control' type='number' min='0' ng-model='num'>
    <h1>{{result}}</h1>

  </div>

</body>
```

The script file :

```
angular.module('myModule',[]).controller('myController',function($scope){

    $scope.num=5;
    $scope.result=$scope.num*2;

});
```

The `result` will only yield **10** for first time then it'll be constant for any changes in `input`

I think it is expected to change the `result` as per as the `input` changes because of the change in `num` property.

I know it will work if I assign a function like :

```
$scope.result=function(){
        return $scope.num*2;
    }
```

and

```
<h1>{{result()}}</h1>
```

but why it does not work without function?

Answer (score 3):

Because when you perform `$scope.result=$scope.num*2;` in the controller, it only gets fired once. If you want it to get fired every digest cycle (whenever there's a change) you need to use a function like you did, or do

```
 <h1>{{num * 2}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

@inorganik answer well.
I will add that IF you want absolutly to change the $scope.result value in controller ( or do other task) when `$scope.num` change his value you can do this :

```
$scope.$watch('num', function (newValues) {
    console.log("you change the value");
    $scope.result = newValues*2
});
```